# Two statements R and S are logically equivalent iff R $\iff$ S is a tautology.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

How do prove the following statement:
"Two statements R and S are logically equivalent iff R↔S is a tautology.
without using a true table.Would I have to use cases?

So far I have done so far is that I have chosen a statement (P $\implies$ Q) $\iff$(~Q $\implies$ ~P) and have create a true table.
R = (P $\implies$ Q) and S is = (~Q $\implies$ ~P).

Comment: You have to use the definition of *logical equivalence* ...

Comment: _Hint for $\Leftarrow$ direction_: If $R$ and $S$ are not logically equivalent, then there is a model $\mathfrak{m}$ with an interpretation $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}$ such that $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}(R) \neq \mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}(S)$. What can you say about $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}(R \leftrightarrow S)$ now?

Comment: Without truth tables, you can use that if $A\to B$ then $A\implies B$ and vise versa. And definition of equivalence, of course

Comment: Can you show me a proof

Comment: Because I'm lost I can't figure it our

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a *reductio ad absurdum*. You always need to prove both directions for iff statements (and therefore generally have two cases) as follows:

[$\Rightarrow$] Suppose that $R$ and $S$ are logically equivalent, but that $R\leftrightarrow S$ is not a tautology. Then there is some valuation $v$ such that $v(R\leftrightarrow S)=false$, which implies that $v(R)\neq v(S)$. But this contradicts the assumption that $R$ and $S$ are logically equivalent.

[$\Leftarrow$] Suppose that $R\leftrightarrow S$ is a tautology, but that $R$ and $S$ are not logically equivalent. Then for some valuation $v$, $v(R)\neq v(S)$. But since $R\leftrightarrow S$ is a tautology, there is no valuation under which this statement is false. Therefore, for every valuation $v$, $v(R)=v(S)$. This contradicts our assumption that $R$ and $S$ are not logically equivalent.